# AppHarbor build failed, looking for file in a weird place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appharbor

I have a project hosted by appharbour. Today I added a login-function menaing that I added a class library to my project. Locally, everything works just fine but I got an error from appharbour when I pushed my changes.

```
Build failed
```

I do not understand much from the log-files but i several places it says that :

D:\temp\rlmwtvm5.2v5\input\AspNet.Identity.RavenDB\SOMEFILE cannot be found.

I find this very odd because I have not saved my project on my D:. I do not even have a folder named temp there...Have anyone seen something like this before and know what to do?

Part of build-log:

```
Build started 6/19/2014 6:03:35 PM.
     1>Project "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
     1>ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
         Building solution configuration "Release|Any CPU".
     1>D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog.sln.metaproj : error MSB3202: The project file "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\AspNet.Identity.RavenDB\AspNet.Identity.RavenDB.csproj" was not found. [D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog.sln]
     1>Project "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog\A_EmmysBlog_Web.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
     1>Project "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\u2vbgm0k.xrz\input\EmmysBlog_Core\EmmysBlog_Core.csproj" (3) on node 2 (default targets).
     3>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
       CoreCompile:
```

Comment: That's most likely where AppHarbor builds your project (and is _their_ temp directory). But, having said that, you probably included the library using a path that is out of context when no other projects are present. That is to say it may reference a place that exists on your drive but not AppHarbor's. To avoid this, it's customary to have a `lib` or `thirdParty` directory (in the solution/project directory) where you directly reference libraries.

Comment: Thank you. What you say defenitley makes sense..Wolud you mind elaborating on the concept of using a third party directory? What exactly goes in it?

Comment: Well, say you have `MyProject/MyProject.sln` you'd add `MyProject/lib` much like (if you're familiar) the NuGet packages directory. There you place any dependencies (which assures they make it to production). If you're using source control, make sure to check in those files as well.